# Definir elementos en una lista, Python

Tags: python, lista

Se tiene una lista A con 50 elementos y se quiere generar una lista B con 30 elementos apartir de la lista A.

Realmente no siempre están fijos esos 50 de la lista A, puede que haya más de 50 elementos, pero tambien puede haber menos pero **siempre** los **suficientes** para que se completen los 30 elementos.

Creo que una pregunta valida podría ser, como puedo tomar los 30 primeros valores de la lista A y ponerlos en mi lista B.

Intento de mi código.

```
x = [327, 315, 247, 190, 374, 203, 318, 285, 204, 327, 246, 228, 262, 278, 266, 335, 275, 342, 275, 307, 223, 236, 350, 223, 364, 206, 273, 242, 213, 268, 250, 296, 302, 280, 286, 198, 233, 369, 209, 230, 275, 376, 219, 394, 344, 213, 332, 376, 256]

lstfx=[]
    
   if len(lstx) == 50:
       lstfx.append(list(range(30)))
       print('valores 30 de x ',lstfx)
```

Comment: La variable `lstx` no está definida. Y `list(range(30))` produce `[0, 1, ..., 29]`, no los 30 primeros valores de `x` (que tampoco aparece mencionado en la operación).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la forma más simple es usar la función list() que obvio crea una lista
y un método de algunos objetos, entre ellos las listas, que es como tomar una rebanada
[] entre corchetes sería toda la lista, pero para la rebanada le decimos desde donde
[0:] el primer índice es 0 por defecto así que si tomás desde el principio no es necesario ponerlo
después va dos puntos: y por último hasta donde, en este caso 30
quedaría así:

```
b = list(x[:30]) 
print(b)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @tincopasan, justo lo había ternimado de resolver con un for y un if cuando llegó tu respuesta mucho más resumida. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: `list` es superflua aquí, ya que `[:30]` ya devuelve una `list`

Comment: @ Danis no me quice poner a explicar las diferencias entre los objetos si hace como vos decis con una tupla , devuelve una tupla por ejemplo, en cambio con list, siempre devolverá una lista

Comment: intente ejecutar esta `print(type(x[:30]) `list` de impresión y no `tuple`

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no se si sea la solución más correcta pero lo solucioné con esto también, sin embargo, es mucho mejor la otra respuesta.

```
A = [327, 315, 247, 190, 374, 203, 318, 285, 204, 327, 246, 228, 262, 278, 266, 335, 275, 342, 275, 307, 223, 236, 350, 223, 364, 206, 273, 242, 213, 268, 250, 296, 302, 280, 286, 198, 233, 369, 209, 230, 275, 376, 219, 394, 344, 213, 332, 376, 256]
B = []

for elemento in A:
    if len(B) < 30:    
        B.append(elemento)
print('valores 30 de x ',B)
print('Largo de B',len(B))
```

Comment: Falta la definición/inicialización de la variable 'A'.

Comment: Tienes razón @Candid Moe, ya actualicé la respuesta.